# How to validate the web page from jQuery using if condition?

Tags: jquery

I am using ASP.net and I have the three text box and two dropdown like this:

```
  <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
       <asp:Label ID="FullNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Full Name : "></asp:Label></div>
         <div class="inputDiv">
           <asp:TextBox ID="FullNameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="smallTxtBox">
           </asp:TextBox></div>
         </div>
            <div class="formlinebreak">
            </div>
              <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
                <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
                  <asp:Label ID="StateNameLabelLabel" runat="server" Text="State  Name"></asp:Label></div>
                    <div class="inputDiv">
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="StateDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                    ValidationGroup="rfvStepOneBasicInput" OnSelectedIndexChanged="StateDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="dropDown">
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                    <div class="formlinebreak">
                    </div>
                      <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
                        <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
                          <asp:Label ID="CityNameLabel" runat="server" Text="City Name"></asp:Label></div>
                            <div class="inputDiv">
                              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CityUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                   <asp:DropDownList ID="CityDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                            ValidationGroup="rfvStepOneBasicInput"  CssClass="dropDown">
                                   </asp:DropDownList>
                                 </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="StateDropDownList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                    </Triggers>
                               </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="formlinebreak">
                        </div>
                        <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
                            <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
                                <asp:Label ID="FeedBackLabel" runat="server" Text="Your FeedBack"></asp:Label></div>
                            <div style="float: left; width: 60%;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="FeedBackTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="multilineTxtBox" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="formlinebreak">
                        </div>
                        <asp:Panel ID="GeneralUserPanel" runat="server" Visible="true">
                            <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
                                <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Your Email ID"></asp:Label></div>
                                <div style="float: left; width: 60%;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="GeneralEmailIDTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="smallTxtBox"></asp:TextBox></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="formlinebreak">
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

I am validating these input from jQuery like this:

```
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
            rules: {
                '<%=FullNameTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
                    required: true
                },
                '<%=StateDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
                    selectNone: true,
                    required: true
                },
                '<%=CityDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
                    selectNone: true,
                    required: true
                },
                '<%=FeedBackTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
                    required: true
                },
                '<%=GeneralEmailIDTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                '<%=FullNameTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
                    required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>Full name is required. </span>"
                },
                '<%=StateDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
                    selectNone: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>State is required. </span>",
                    required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>State is required. </span>"
                },
                '<%=CityDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
                    selectNone: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>City is required. </span>",
                    required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>City is required. </span>"
                },
                '<%=FeedBackTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
                    required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>Feedback is required. </span>"
                },
                '<%=GeneralEmailIDTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
                    required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>Emil-ID is required. </span>"
                }
            }
        });
```

But I want to validate the city only when the State ID is 1. I have tried the following code in `document.ready`:

```
     if ($('[id$=StateDropDownList]').val() == "1") {
         $("#aspnetForm").validate({  //Imp #aspnetForm is the ID of the <form> in site.Master
            rules: {
            '<%=CityDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
                    required: true,
                    selectNone: true
                }
            },
             messages:{
            '<%=CityDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
                    selectNone: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>City is required. </span>",
                    required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>City is required. </span>"
                }
             });
        }
```

But I even can't validate. I want to validate all except city dropdown simultaneously I want to validate city dropdown when user select the stateid=1. How can I do this?

Comment: Which jQuery API are you using?

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Did you try? please mark as answer if it worked.

Comment: Sir, I have tried this but it not working as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
  '<%=PhoneNoTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
       required: function () {
           if ($("[id$=MobileNoTextBox]").val() == "")
            return true;
            else
             return false;
            },
       number: true,
       minlength: 10,
       maxlength: 15
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the depends option

```
$("#aspnetForm").validate({
    rules: {
        '<%=FullNameTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
            required: true
        },
            '<%=StateDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
            selectNone: true,
            required: true
        },
            '<%=CityDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
            selectNone: {
                param: true,
                depends: function () {
                    return $('#<%=StateDropDownList.UniqueID %>').val() == 1
                }
            },
            required: {
                param: true,
                depends: function () {
                    return $('#<%=StateDropDownList.UniqueID %>').val() == 1
                }
            }
        },
            '<%=FeedBackTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
            required: true
        },
            '<%=GeneralEmailIDTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        '<%=FullNameTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
            required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>Full name is required. </span>"
        },
            '<%=StateDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
            selectNone: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>State is required. </span>",
            required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>State is required. </span>"
        },
            '<%=CityDropDownList.UniqueID %>': {
            selectNone: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>City is required. </span>",
            required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>City is required. </span>"
        },
            '<%=FeedBackTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
            required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>Feedback is required. </span>"
        },
            '<%=GeneralEmailIDTextBox.UniqueID %>': {
            required: "<span  style='color:#F87126;padding-left:10px; font-size:smaller;'>Emil-ID is required. </span>"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#frm_step1").validate({
            rules: {
                'CampaignStartDate': {
                    required: function(){
                        return ($('input[name="data[Campaign][start_now]"]:checked').val() == 'no');
                    }
                },
                'CampaignEndDate': {
                    required: function(){
                        return ($('input[name="data[Campaign][start_now]"]:checked').val() == 'no');
                    }
                },
                'countries': {
                    required: function(){
                        return ($('input[name="data[Campaign][locations]"]:checked').val() == 'no');
                    }
                },
                'CampaignBudget': {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                    min: 100
                },
                'CampaignPerDayBudget': {
                    required: function(){
                        return ($('input[name="data[Campaign][start_now]"]:checked').val() == 'all');
                    },
                    number: function(){
                        return ($('input[name="data[Campaign][start_now]"]:checked').val() == 'all');
                    }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                'CampaignBudget': {
                    min: 'Please enter min. budget of <?php echo DEFAULT_CURRENCY ?>100.'
                }
            }
        })
});
```